# Spring FTP Inbound channel not working

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-sftp

I am trying to use FtpInboundFileSynchronizer and unable to fix it. It is not reporting any problem and also not working. I am referring code from 
http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ftp.html#_configuring_with_java_configuration_10

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;

import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPFile;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringBootConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.InboundChannelAdapter;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.ServiceActivator;
import org.springframework.integration.core.MessageSource;
import org.springframework.integration.file.filters.AcceptOnceFileListFilter;
import org.springframework.integration.file.remote.session.CachingSessionFactory;
import org.springframework.integration.file.remote.session.Session;
import org.springframework.integration.file.remote.session.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.integration.ftp.filters.FtpSimplePatternFileListFilter;
import org.springframework.integration.ftp.inbound.FtpInboundFileSynchronizer;
import org.springframework.integration.ftp.inbound.FtpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource;
import org.springframework.integration.ftp.session.DefaultFtpSessionFactory;
import org.springframework.messaging.Message;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandler;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException;

@SpringBootConfiguration
public class FtpJavaApplication {

private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(FtpJavaApplication.class);
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LOG.info("1");
    new SpringApplicationBuilder(FtpJavaApplication.class)
        .web(false)
        .run(args);
}

@Bean
public SessionFactory<FTPFile> ftpSessionFactory() {
    LOG.info("2");
    DefaultFtpSessionFactory sf = new DefaultFtpSessionFactory();
    sf.setHost("host");
    sf.setPort(port);
    sf.setUsername("userid");
    sf.setPassword("password");
    return new CachingSessionFactory<FTPFile>(sf);
}

@Bean
public FtpInboundFileSynchronizer ftpInboundFileSynchronizer() {
    LOG.info("3");
    Session<FTPFile> session = ftpSessionFactory().getSession();
    try {
        System.out.println(3.1);
        String[] listNames = session.listNames(".");
        System.out.println(3.2);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(listNames));
        System.out.println(3.3);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    FtpInboundFileSynchronizer fileSynchronizer = new FtpInboundFileSynchronizer(ftpSessionFactory());
    fileSynchronizer.setDeleteRemoteFiles(false);
    fileSynchronizer.setRemoteDirectory(".");
    fileSynchronizer.setFilter(new FtpSimplePatternFileListFilter("*"));
    return fileSynchronizer;
}

@Bean
@InboundChannelAdapter(channel = "ftpChannel", poller =    @Poller(fixedDelay = "5000"))
public MessageSource<File> ftpMessageSource() {
    LOG.info("4");
    FtpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource source =
            new FtpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource(ftpInboundFileSynchronizer());
    source.setLocalDirectory(new File("c:/temp/ftp"));
    source.setAutoCreateLocalDirectory(true);
    source.setLocalFilter(new AcceptOnceFileListFilter<File>());
    return source;
}

@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "ftpChannel")
public MessageHandler handler() {
    LOG.info("5");
    return new MessageHandler() {

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message<?> message) throws MessagingException {
            System.out.println(message.getPayload());
        }

    };
}
```

}

I am able to list out all files in remote directory if use ftpSession object. However synchronization is not working and files did not FTP to local directory. No error reported by application in logs.

```
[2016-12-22 09:57:43,   314]DEBUG[main]  (SpringApplication.java:689) - Loading source class FtpJavaApplication
[2016-12-22 09:57:43,   466]DEBUG[main]  (ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:252) - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Named' annotation found and supported for component scanning
[2016-12-22 09:57:43,   480]INFO [main]  (AbstractApplicationContext.java:581) - Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@166ebe0: startup date [Thu Dec 22 09:57:43 EST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
[2016-12-22 09:57:43,   480]DEBUG[main]  (AbstractApplicationContext.java:615) - Bean factory for org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@166ebe0: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@55dd0c: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerProcessor,org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerFactory,ftpJavaApplication]; root of factory hierarchy
[2016-12-22 09:57:43,   491]DEBUG[main]  (DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:221) - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor'
[2016-12-22 09:57:43,   491]DEBUG[main]  (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:448) - Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor'
[2016-12-22 09:57:43,   495]DEBUG[main]  (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:529) - Eagerly caching bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor' to allow for resolving potential circular references
[2016-12-22 09:57:43,   496]DEBUG[main]  (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:484) - Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor'
[2016-12-22 09:57:43,   518]DEBUG[main]  (ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:256) - Registering bean definition for @Bean method FtpJavaApplication.ftpSessionFactory()
[2016-12-22 09:57:43,   519]DEBUG[main]  (ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:256) - Registering bean definition for @Bean method FtpJavaApplication.ftpMessageSource()
[2016-12-22 09:57:43,   519]DEBUG[main]  (ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:256) - Registering bean definition for @Bean method FtpJavaApplication.handler()
[2016-12-22 09:57:43,   520]DEBUG[main]  (ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:256) - Registering bean definition for @Bean method FtpJavaApplication.ftpInboundFileSynchronizer()
[2016-12-22 09:57:43,   581]DEBUG[main]  (ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:109) - Successfully enhanced FtpJavaApplication; enhanced class name is: FtpJavaApplication$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a6fc584e
[2016-12-22 09:57:43,   582]DEBUG[main]  (ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:409) - Replacing bean definition 'ftpJavaApplication' existing class 'FtpJavaApplication' with enhanced class 'FtpJavaApplication$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a6fc584e'
[2016-12-22 09:57:43,   582]DEBUG[main]  (MutablePropertySources.java:159) - Removing [applicationConfigurationProperties] PropertySource
[2016-12-22 09:57:43,   582]DEBUG[main]  (MutablePropertySources.java:159) - Removing [defaultProperties] PropertySource
[2016-12-22 09:57:43,   584]DEBUG[main]  (DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:221) - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor'
[2016-12-22 09:57:43,   584]DEBUG[main]  (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:448) - Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor'
[2016-12-22 09:57:43,   585]INFO [main]  (AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:155) - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
[2016-12-22 09:57:43,   585]DEBUG[main]  (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:529) - Eagerly caching bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor' to allow for resolving potential circular references
[2016-12-22 09:57:43,   585]DEBUG[main]  (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:484) - Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor'
[2016-12-22 09:57:43,   585]DEBUG[main]  (DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:221) - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor'
[2016-12-22 09:57:43,   585]DEBUG[main]  (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:448) - Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor'
[2016-12-22 09:57:43,   586]DEBUG[main]  (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:529) - Eagerly caching bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor' to allow for resolving potential circular references
[2016-12-22 09:57:43,   586]DEBUG[main]  (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:484) - Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor'
[2016-12-22 09:57:43,   586]DEBUG[main]  (DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:221) - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor'
[2016-12-22 09:57:43,   586]DEBUG[main]  (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:448) - Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor'
[2016-12-22 09:57:43,   589]DEBUG[main]  (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:529) - Eagerly caching bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor' to allow for resolving potential circular references
[2016-12-22 09:57:43,   589]DEBUG[main]  (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:484) - Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor'
[2016-12-22 09:57:43,   589]DEBUG[main]  (DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:221) - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor'
[2016-12-22 09:57:43,   589]DEBUG[main]  (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:448) - Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor'
[2016-12-22 09:57:43,   589]DEBUG[main]  (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:529) - Eagerly caching bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor' to allow for resolving potential circular references
[2016-12-22 09:57:43,   589]DEBUG[main]  (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:484) - Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor'
[2016-12-22 09:57:43,   590]DEBUG[main]  (DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:221) - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhancedConfigurationProcessor'
[2016-12-22 09:57:43,   590]DEBUG[main]  (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:448) - Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhancedConfigurationProcessor'
[2016-12-22 09:57:43,   590]DEBUG[main]  (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:529) - Eagerly caching bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhancedConfigurationProcessor' to allow for resolving potential circular references
[2016-12-22 09:57:43,   590]DEBUG[main]  (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:484) - Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhancedConfigurationProcessor'
[2016-12-22 09:57:43,   592]DEBUG[main]  (AbstractApplicationContext.java:728) - Unable to locate MessageSource with name 'messageSource': using default [org.springframework.context.support.DelegatingMessageSource@13bda92]
[2016-12-22 09:57:43,   592]DEBUG[main]  (AbstractApplicationContext.java:752) - Unable to locate ApplicationEventMulticaster with name 'applicationEventMulticaster': using default [org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster@4bb45b]
[2016-12-22 09:57:43,   593]DEBUG[main]  (DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:744) - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@55dd0c: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerProcessor,org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerFactory,ftpJavaApplication,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhancedConfigurationProcessor,ftpSessionFactory,ftpMessageSource,handler,ftpInboundFileSynchronizer]; root of factory hierarchy
[2016-12-22 09:57:43,   593]DEBUG[main]  (AbstractBeanFactory.java:251) - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor'
[2016-12-22 09:57:43,   593]DEBUG[main]  (AbstractBeanFactory.java:251) - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor'
[2016-12-22 09:57:43,   593]DEBUG[main]  (AbstractBeanFactory.java:251) - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor'
[2016-12-22 09:57:43,   593]DEBUG[main]  (AbstractBeanFactory.java:251) - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor'
[2016-12-22 09:57:43,   593]DEBUG[main]  (DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:221) - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerProcessor'
[2016-12-22 09:57:43,   593]DEBUG[main]  (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:448) - Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerProcessor'
[2016-12-22 09:57:43,   597]DEBUG[main]  (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:529) - Eagerly caching bean 'org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerProcessor' to allow for resolving potential circular references
[2016-12-22 09:57:43,   600]DEBUG[main]  (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:484) - Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerProcessor'
[2016-12-22 09:57:43,   600]DEBUG[main]  (DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:221) - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerFactory'
[2016-12-22 09:57:43,   600]DEBUG[main]  (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:448) - Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerFactory'
[2016-12-22 09:57:43,   600]DEBUG[main]  (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:529) - Eagerly caching bean 'org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerFactory' to allow for resolving potential circular references
[2016-12-22 09:57:43,   602]DEBUG[main]  (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:484) - Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerFactory'
[2016-12-22 09:57:43,   602]DEBUG[main]  (DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:221) - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'ftpJavaApplication'
[2016-12-22 09:57:43,   602]DEBUG[main]  (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:448) - Creating instance of bean 'ftpJavaApplication'
[2016-12-22 09:57:43,   603]DEBUG[main]  (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:529) - Eagerly caching bean 'ftpJavaApplication' to allow for resolving potential circular references
[2016-12-22 09:57:43,   605]DEBUG[main]  (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:484) - Finished creating instance of bean 'ftpJavaApplication'
[2016-12-22 09:57:43,   605]DEBUG[main]  (AbstractBeanFactory.java:251) - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor'
[2016-12-22 09:57:43,   606]DEBUG[main]  (AbstractBeanFactory.java:251) - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhancedConfigurationProcessor'
[2016-12-22 09:57:43,   606]DEBUG[main]  (DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:221) - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'ftpSessionFactory'
[2016-12-22 09:57:43,   606]DEBUG[main]  (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:448) - Creating instance of bean 'ftpSessionFactory'
[2016-12-22 09:57:43,   608]DEBUG[main]  (AbstractBeanFactory.java:251) - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'ftpJavaApplication'
[2016-12-22 09:57:43,   621]INFO [main]  (FtpJavaApplication.java:39) - 2
[2016-12-22 09:57:43,   625]DEBUG[main]  (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:529) - Eagerly caching bean 'ftpSessionFactory' to allow for resolving potential circular references
[2016-12-22 09:57:43,   627]DEBUG[main]  (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:484) - Finished creating instance of bean 'ftpSessionFactory'
[2016-12-22 09:57:43,   627]DEBUG[main]  (DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:221) - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'ftpMessageSource'
[2016-12-22 09:57:43,   627]DEBUG[main]  (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:448) - Creating instance of bean 'ftpMessageSource'
[2016-12-22 09:57:43,   627]DEBUG[main]  (AbstractBeanFactory.java:251) - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'ftpJavaApplication'
[2016-12-22 09:57:43,   628]INFO [main]  (FtpJavaApplication.java:73) - 4
[2016-12-22 09:57:43,   631]DEBUG[main]  (DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:221) - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'ftpInboundFileSynchronizer'
[2016-12-22 09:57:43,   631]DEBUG[main]  (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:448) - Creating instance of bean 'ftpInboundFileSynchronizer'
[2016-12-22 09:57:43,   631]DEBUG[main]  (AbstractBeanFactory.java:251) - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'ftpJavaApplication'
[2016-12-22 09:57:43,   631]INFO [main]  (FtpJavaApplication.java:50) - 3
[2016-12-22 09:57:43,   631]DEBUG[main]  (AbstractBeanFactory.java:251) - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'ftpSessionFactory'
[2016-12-22 09:57:43,   651]DEBUG[main]  (AbstractFtpSessionFactory.java:197) - Connected to server [abcd:21]
[2016-12-22 09:57:44,   845]DEBUG[main]  (SimplePool.java:190) - Obtained new org.springframework.integration.ftp.session.FtpSession@1c19a70.
3.1
3.2
[a.txt, b.txt, c.txt, d.txt]
3.3
[2016-12-22 10:01:08,204813]DEBUG[main]  (AbstractBeanFactory.java:251) - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'ftpSessionFactory'
[2016-12-22 10:01:08,204842]DEBUG[main]  (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:529) - Eagerly caching bean 'ftpInboundFileSynchronizer' to allow for resolving potential circular references
[2016-12-22 10:01:08,204845]DEBUG[main]  (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1620) - Invoking afterPropertiesSet() on bean with name 'ftpInboundFileSynchronizer'
[2016-12-22 10:01:08,204850]DEBUG[main]  (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:484) - Finished creating instance of bean 'ftpInboundFileSynchronizer'
[2016-12-22 10:01:08,204855]DEBUG[main]  (PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.java:317) - Resolved classpath location [META-INF/spring.integration.default.properties] to resources [URL [jar:file:/C:/data/.m2/repository/org/springframework/integration/spring-integration-core/4.3.1.RELEASE/spring-integration-core-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar!/META-INF/spring.integration.default.properties]]
[2016-12-22 10:01:08,204857]INFO [main]  (PropertiesLoaderSupport.java:172) - Loading properties file from URL [jar:file:/C:/data/.m2/repository/org/springframework/integration/spring-integration-core/4.3.1.RELEASE/spring-integration-core-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar!/META-INF/spring.integration.default.properties]
[2016-12-22 10:01:08,204863]DEBUG[main]  (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:529) - Eagerly caching bean 'ftpMessageSource' to allow for resolving potential circular references
[2016-12-22 10:01:08,204871]DEBUG[main]  (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1620) - Invoking afterPropertiesSet() on bean with name 'ftpMessageSource'
[2016-12-22 10:01:08,204872]DEBUG[main]  (IntegrationUtils.java:79) - No MessageBuilderFactory with name 'messageBuilderFactory' found: No bean named 'messageBuilderFactory' is defined, using default.
[2016-12-22 10:01:08,204873]DEBUG[main]  (IntegrationUtils.java:79) - No MessageBuilderFactory with name 'messageBuilderFactory' found: No bean named 'messageBuilderFactory' is defined, using default.
[2016-12-22 10:01:08,204873]DEBUG[main]  (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:484) - Finished creating instance of bean 'ftpMessageSource'
[2016-12-22 10:01:08,204874]DEBUG[main]  (DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:221) - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'handler'
[2016-12-22 10:01:08,204874]DEBUG[main]  (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:448) - Creating instance of bean 'handler'
[2016-12-22 10:01:08,204874]DEBUG[main]  (AbstractBeanFactory.java:251) - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'ftpJavaApplication'
[2016-12-22 10:01:08,204874]INFO [main]  (FtpJavaApplication.java:85) - 5
[2016-12-22 10:01:08,204875]DEBUG[main]  (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:529) - Eagerly caching bean 'handler' to allow for resolving potential circular references
[2016-12-22 10:01:08,204876]DEBUG[main]  (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:484) - Finished creating instance of bean 'handler'
[2016-12-22 10:01:08,204876]DEBUG[main]  (AbstractBeanFactory.java:251) - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'ftpInboundFileSynchronizer'
[2016-12-22 10:01:08,204877]DEBUG[main]  (AbstractBeanFactory.java:251) - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerFactory'
[2016-12-22 10:01:08,204891]DEBUG[main]  (AbstractApplicationContext.java:779) - Unable to locate LifecycleProcessor with name 'lifecycleProcessor': using default [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor@b346ea]
[2016-12-22 10:01:08,204891]DEBUG[main]  (AbstractBeanFactory.java:251) - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'ftpMessageSource'
[2016-12-22 10:01:08,204891]DEBUG[main]  (AbstractBeanFactory.java:251) - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'lifecycleProcessor'
[2016-12-22 10:01:08,204896]DEBUG[main]  (PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:91) - Could not find key 'spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain' in any property source
[2016-12-22 10:01:08,204898]INFO [main]  (StartupInfoLogger.java:57) - Started FtpJavaApplication in 204.804 seconds (JVM running for 205.247)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the wrong annotation: `@SpringBootConfiguration` should be `@SpringBootApplication`.

That will add `@EnableIntegration`.

Comment: Thank you very much. It is working fine after this change.